# iOS - Take a picture and record video using long press gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera

I'm trying to do take picture and record video using long press gesture, I am getting related searches. Is it possible to do using `UIImagePickerController`?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: yes, It's possible take picture on single tap and record video on long gesture. Just find in google you will get your answer

Comment: Gopi Ch  in which way do you want to implement this?

Comment: Do you want to do both simultaneously?